# How to use C# progress bar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, progress-bar

I want to ask about how to use the c# 2010 progress bar ? . 
I know the properties ( Max, Min and Value ) and also to increment the value. 
But i don't know to use it while loading data from database for example. 
Or how to use it by downloading a file from database.
Or loading datagridview (e.g.with 1000 row), so it takes time, but i want to display a progress bar for it.

How can i know the max value for these examples? i mean the concept of the use of progress bar.

Comment: Sometimes you can do an inexpensive operation to determine the volume of work to be done, e.g. a SQL query that counts rows, and use that to set the limits. Sometimes you can't and a progress bar is the wrong tool. A status line that indicates progress, e.g. "Analyzing entrail 42...", may make more sense as it can show progress, but doesn't attempt to indicate the fraction of the work completed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you suggest a status indicator progess ?

Comment: Typically I'll use a `Label` and update it as work proceeds, e.g: "Initializing...", "Connecting to FTP site...", "Analyzing directory of 42 files...", "Processed 100 widgets..." (updated roughly once a second, perhaps every 100 widgets), "Processed 666 widgets in 13.79 seconds with 0 errors.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest getting the size of byte from the data your dealing with, then use an asynchronous operation which will pass parameter to another method each time new bytes are gained.

in this case you can use something like this:

setProgress(byte[] bytesx){

progressbar.value = dProgress = 100.0 * bytesx / FileSize;
}

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you please explain more about asynch operation in c# winform ? you mean two threads ?